# cosine similarity doc vectors and word vectors for topical prevalence using doc2vec

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I have a corpus of 250k Dutch news articles 2010-2020 to which I've applied word2vec models to uncover relationships between sets of neutral words and dimensions (e.g. good-bad). Since my aim is also to analyze the prevalence of certain topics over time, I was thinking of using doc2vec instead so as to simultaneously learn word and document embeddings. The 'prevalence' of topics in a document could then be calculated as the cosine similarities between doc vectors and word embeddings (or combinations of word vectors). In this way, I can calculate the annual topical prevalence in the corpus and see whether there's any changes over time. An example of such an approach can be found [here](https://export.arxiv.org/pdf/1707.03490).

My issue is that the avg. yearly cosine similarities yield really strange results. As an example, the cosine similarities between document vectors and a mixture of keywords related to covid-19/coronavirus show a decrease in topical prevalence since 2016 (which obviously cannot be the case).

My question is whether the approach that I'm following is actually valid. Or that maybe there's something that I'm missing. A 250k documents and 100k + vocabulary should be sufficient enough?

Below is the code that I've written:

```
# Doc2Vec model 
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
docs = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(tokenized_docs)]
d2vmodel = Doc2Vec(docs, min_count = 5, vector_size = 200, window = 10, dm = 1)
docvecs = d2vmodel.docvecs
wordvecs = d2vmodel.wv
    
# normalize vector 
from numpy.linalg import norm
def nrm(x):
  return x/norm(x)

# topical prevalence per doc
def topicalprevalence(topic, docvecs, wordvecs):
  proj_lst = []
  for i in range(0, len(docvecs)):
    topic_lst = []
    for j in topic: 
      cossim =  nrm(docvecs[i]) @ nrm(wordvecs[j])
      topic_lst.append(cossim)
    topic_avg = sum(topic_lst) / len(topic_lst)
    proj_lst.append(topic_avg)
  topicsyrs = { 
      'topic': proj_lst,
      'year': df['datetime'].dt.year
  }
  return pd.DataFrame(topicsyrs)

# avg topic prevalence per year
def avgtopicyear(topic, docvecs, wordvecs):
  docs = topicalprevalence(topic, docvecs, wordvecs)
  return pd.DataFrame(docs.groupby("year")["topic"].mean())

# run 
covid = ['corona', 'coronapandemie', 'coronacrisis', 'covid', 'pandemie']
covid_scores = topicalprevalence(covid, docvecs, wordvecs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word-vec-to-doc-vec relatioships in modes that train both are interesting, but a bit hard to characterize as to what they really mean. In a sense the CBOW-like mode of `dm=1` (PV-DM) mixes doc-vectors in as one equal word among the whole `window`, when training to predict the 'target' word. But in the skip-gram-mixed mode `dm=0, dbow_words=1`, there'll be `window` count context-word-vec-to-target-word pair cycles to every 1 doc-vec-to-target-word pair cycle, changing the relative weight.

So if you saw a big improvement in `dm=0, dbow_words=1`, it might also be because that made the model relatively more word-to-word trained. Varying `window` is another way to change that balance, or increase `epochs`, in plain `dm=1` mode – which should also result in doc/word compatible training, though perhaps not at the same rate/balance.

Whether a single `topicalprevalence()` mean vector for a full year would actually be reflective of individual word occurrences for a major topic may or may not be a valid conjecture, depending on possible other changes in the training data. Something like a difference in the relative mix of other major categories in the corpus might swamp even a giant new news topic. (EG: what if in y2020 some new section or subsidiary with a different focus, like entertainment, launched? It *might* swamp the effects of other words, especially when compressing down to a *single* vector of some particular dimensionality.)

Someting like a clustering of the year's articles, and identification of the closest 1 or N clusters to the target-words, with their similarities, might be more reflective even if the population of articles in changing. Or, a plot of each year's full set of articles as a histogram-of-similarities to the target-words - which might show a 'lump' of individual articles (not losing their distinctiveness to a full-year average) developing, over time, closer to the new phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. 

Training indeed took at least three times more time with 'dm=0, dbow_words=1'. 

From a qualitative perspective the results seem valid. The corona virus topic prevalence, for instance, really spikes in 2020. Also a close inspection of the highest scoring documents in various years makes a lot of sense.

Comment: As to the topicalprevalence function, I'll give your suggestions a try. Would you say that changing year to month would be an easier way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Going monthly might help, or might hurt - depends on relative quantity/quality/blaance of data per period. It's more the assumption that the mean of all docs in a period would neessarily get closer to certain words - I suspect it could, with sufficient data & good moel parameters, but I could imagine certain kinds of data insufficiency orimbalance, or model weaknesses, that mgith overwhelm that expected/desired effect. These sorts of 'dense embeddings' are inherently a compression that discards lots of the underlying data - but hopefull (when tuned/used well) reveal important/deeper patterns.

Comment: I guess I could then also plot a boxplot around each monthly / yearly mean to illustrate variance? I think that the main argument of my analysis will revolve around word embeddings, but people (in the social sciences) always want to see how things evolve over time. So I'd thought that I could overcome that issue by training docs and words in the same space using `dm=0, dbow_words=1`. I guess another option would be to train different word2vec models for different time periods as some people do, but honestly I think that the doc2vec solution yields more reliable results.

Comment: The data itself are pretty balenced throughout the years. They're also all derived from a single Dutch news source.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that setting parameters to `dm=0, dbow_words=1` allows for training documents and words in the same space, now yielding valid results.

Comment: Note that plain `dm=1` mode (aka "PV-DM") should also succeed in training both words & docs as vectors, with compatibile vector-spaces. Only `dm=0` (without `dbow_words=1`) uses the pure "PV-DBOW" mode, which *doesn't* train word-vectors at all, leaving them randomly-initialized (untrained). So, I wouldn't expect a toggler from `dm=1` to `dm=0, dbow_words=1` to remedy a major problem - except insofar as it may result in somewhat *more* net training (& in a slightly-different style). Increasing the intensity of `dm=1` training (as if by more `epochs` etc) might have the same effect.